# What's wrong with `var myEval = eval; myEval("2+2")`

Tags: javascript, eval

As per [MDN-EVAL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

> You cannot indirectly use the eval function by invoking it via a name other than eval(); if you do, a runtime error might occur. For example, you should not use the following code:

```
var x = 2; //1
var y = 4; //2
var myEval = eval; //3
eval("x + y"); //4
myEval("x + y"); //5
```

Normal cases JavaScript would not have minded for `var someReference = someFunctionReference;` but yes eval is the special case so I can expect some surprises.

Now let's see some of the following runs in non-strict mode

1. Firefox/Aurora(V39.0) does not mind and the above code runs well.
2. Chrome(V 42.0.2311.135 m) with V8 4.2.77.18 runs well. *(V8 version taken from chrome://version/)*
3. Node(V0.10.35) with V8 3.14.5.9 complains error that `x` is undefined at line number 5 *(V8 version taken from node -e "console.log(process.versions.v8)")*

Now my query is why are there different behavior and how/when doing this coding style brings risk to my program.

P.S.: the line `//4` does not complain any error in any of the run And My assumption in the above runs that chrome/firefox console run in non-strict mode.

Comment: Likely, the restriction is for some form of security reason. But did you try `eval("x + y")` in Node to see if referencing `eval` is related to your problem or a red herrring?

Comment: The `eval` at line `//4` does not run into error in any of the run

Comment: That quote from MDN is frankly rubbish; it's probably a left-over from several years ago, before the behavior of indirect `eval` was established. MDN is a community-edited site. Although the quality is generally very high, sometimes you get the odd bit that's off. This is one of those times. There are plenty of perfectly valid uses of indirect `eval`. I'm off to fix it...

Comment: Fixed the MDN article.

Comment: Yea... I could see the updates... Thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is special. As of ES5 (~2009), a direct call to `eval` works within the current scope, but an *indirect* call to it as with your `myEval` works in global scope. This is detailed in [§10.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2) and [§15.1.2.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1.1).

So if your code is being run within a function, e.g.:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 2;
    var y = 4;
    var myEval = eval;
    myEval("x + y");
}
```

...then *correct* behavior as of ES5 would be to complain that `x` does not exist.

If your code is at global scope outside of all functions, e.g.:

```
var x = 2;
var y = 4;
var myEval = eval;
myEval("x + y");
```

...then correct behavior is to get the result `6`. Full example below.

> Now my query is why are there different behavior...

If you were running that code in the browser *console*, it may be down to the console implementation (e.g., one console may evaluate your code within a function, another globally). The console is a special environment, scope-related things like this are best tested with a normal page.

> and how/when doing this coding style brings risk to my program.

There's no significant difference in *risk* using `eval` directly or indirectly. The risk comes from using `eval` (at all) on input you don't control. If you're taking input from the user and running it immediately on their computer, the risk is mostly to them. However, if you're taking input from one user, then later running that via `eval` on *another* user's computer or on your server, that's a significant risk: You're allowing that user to reach out and run code on a machine that isn't theirs.

> P.S.: My assumption in the above runs that chrome/firefox console run in non-strict mode.

Strict mode doesn't affect this aspect of `eval`. (It *does* affect other aspects of it, in particular whether it can create variables within a local scope [it can in loose mode, it can't in strict mode]; that's also in §10.4.2.)

---

**Live Example:**

```js
function direct() {
  var x = 2;
  var y = 4;
  return eval("x + y");
}

function indirect() {
  var x = 2;
  var y = 4;
  var myEval = eval;
  return myEval("x + y");
}

snippet.log("Direct (within function):");
try {
  snippet.log("Got " + direct());
}
catch (e) {
  snippet.log("Got exception: " + e.message);
}

snippet.log("Indirect (within function):");
try {
  snippet.log("Got " + indirect());
}
catch (e) {
  snippet.log("Got exception: " + e.message);
}

var globalX = 2;
var globalY = 4;

snippet.log("Direct (at global scope):");
try {
  snippet.log("Got " + eval("globalX + globalY"));
}
catch (e) {
  snippet.log("Got exception: " + e.message);
}

snippet.log("Indirect (at global scope):");
var myGlobalEval = eval;
try {
  snippet.log("Got " + myGlobalEval("globalX + globalY"));
}
catch (e) {
  snippet.log("Got exception: " + e.message);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Correct behavior is to show:

```
Direct (within function):
Got 6
Indirect (within function):
Got exception: x is not defined
Direct (at global scope):
Got 6
Indirect (at global scope):
Got 6
```

Comment: Clear explanation for what I asked... nice references direct from origin... I wish I could upvote this answer twice :) Thanks ;)